# iPhone Safari does not auto scale back down on portrait->landscape->portrait

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, iphone, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have a very simple HTML page with this META tag for the iPhone:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
```

Using the iPhone Safari, when the page loads in portrait mode it looks fine and the width fits the screen.
When I rotate the iPhone to landscape mode the web page is auto resized to fit the landscape width. Good, this is what I want.

But when I rotate back from landscape, the page is not resized back to fit the portrait width like it was before. It remains in the landscape width.

I want the iPhone to set it back to the right width automatically, just like it did for the landscape mode.
I don't think this should involve orientation listeners because it is all done automatically and I don't have any special styling for the different modes.

Why doesn't the iPhone resize the web page back in portrait mode?
How do I fix this?

### UPDATE

I managed to get the iPhone to auto resize down but with a strange phenomenon of doing it only after an even number of rotations... Very very strange.
I use this META tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Here's what I have to do to get it auto resized:
1. On load in portrait -> looks good.
2. Rotate to landscape -> resized to fit screen.
3. Rotate back to portrait -> no resize back.
4. Rotate to landscape -> still in size for landscape.
5. Rotate to portrait -> resized down to fit portrait screen.

Can someone explain this behavior??
I still want to know how to fix this and appreciate any assistance.

Thanks!
Tom.

Comment: ##Meta viewport tags do not fix this problem I've tried all of the settings listed and they do nothing to fix the horizontal to vertical resize. I assume [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/) will fix this but as of yet it has the same problem.

Answer (score 31):

This has to be a bug in iOS 4 Safari. Here's what my behavior was with the following meta tags (the second tag is to make it full screen):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

Page would scale correctly when going from portrait to landscape until I used the pop up keyboard to enter a value in a field - then it would stop scaling. Which would mean if I used the keyboard in landscape it would be too large when I went to portrait, or vice versa.

Switching using the following meta tags fixed it... Thanks to the other answers on this page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

Comment: This works but will prevent the user from using pinch to zoom.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on my 3GS 3.1.3, even though I couldn't get it to ever become the right size again after landscape mode. But when I removed "height=device-height" the page scaled down correctly every time. So my meta looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

I'd like to be able to use the height attribute to lock the height, but it seems like they don't mix too well.

Comment: Hi,
You are right here, these 2 don't go together. But meanwhile, I found a workaround for this. Might work for you too. The reason to have the height is to be able to hide the address bar on page load by scrolling 1px down. So I now use this meta:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
and at the end of the html page I added this:
<div style="height:350px"></div>

Comment: The address bar hides when you do the following. The height attribute does not do that.
http://www.iphonemicrosites.com/tutorials/how-to-hide-the-address-bar-in-mobilesafari/

I'll try the height:350px - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put one more thing `minimum-scale=1.0` so it would like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using ExtJs (sencha touch), it seems Good

```
Ext.setup({
  tabletStartupScreen: 'images/tablet_startup_768x1004.png',
  phoneStartupScreen: 'images/phone_startup_320x460.png',
  tabletIcon: 'images/tablet_icon_72x72.png',
  phoneIcon: 'images/phone_icon_72x72.png',
  icon: 'images/icon_72x72.png',
  statusBarStyle: 'black',
  glossOnIcon: true,
  fullscreen: true,
  onReady: function() {
    var viewport = null;                                                                                
    var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');                                                  
    for(var i = 0, length = metas.length; i < length; ++i){                                             
      var meta = metas[i];                                                                              
      // already Extjs addedMetaTags                                                                    
      if(meta.name == 'viewport'){                                                                      
        viewport = Ext.get(meta);                                                                       
        break;                                                                                          
      }                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                   
    if(null == viewport){                                                                               
      viewport = Ext.get(document.createElement('meta'));                                               
    }                                                                                                   

    if(window.navigator.standalone){                                                                    
      // IMPORTANT!!! not set to height=device-height when iphone standalone mode was ignored "scale" settings           
      viewport.set({                                                                                    
        name: 'viewport',                                                                               
        content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'
      });                                                                                               
    } else {                                                                                            
      // IMPORTANT!!! set to height=device-height when !standalone mode; behav window.innerHeight = fullscreen size
      viewport.set({                                                                                    
        name: 'viewport',                                                                               
        content: 'height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'
      });                                                                                               
    } 
  }
});
```

other devices compatible with ...

```
var watcher = {
  handlers: [],
  dimentions: {width:0, height: 0},
  fullscreenize: false,
  orientLandscape: function (){
    return 90 === Math.abs(window.orientation);
  },
  orientPortrait: function (){
    return !this.orientLandscape();
  },
  width: function (){
    return this.dimentions.width;
  },
  height: function (){
    return this.dimentions.height;
  },
  changeDimentions: function (evt){
    var self = this;
    (function (){
      if(self.fullscreenize){
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
      }

      self.dimentions = Ext.Element.getViewSize();
      self.fireOnchange();
    }).defer(100);
  },
  init: function (){
    if('onorientationchange' in window){
      Event.observe(window, 'orientationchange', this.changeDimentions.bind(this));
    } else {
      Event.observe(window, 'resize', this.changeDimentions.bind(this));
    }
    Event.observe(window, 'load', this.changeDimentions.bind(this));
  },
  fullScreen: function (){
    this.fullscreenize = true;
    var self = this;
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function (){
      (function (){
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);

        self.changeDimentions();
      }).defer(100);
    });
  },
  fireOnchange: function(){
    var self = this;
    self.handlers.each(function (handler){
      handler.apply(null, [self]);
    });
  },
  onchange: function (handler){
    this.handlers.push(handler);
  }
};
watcher.init();
watcher.fullScreen();

aComponent = Ext.extend(Ext.Component, {
  initComponent: function (){
    watcher.onchange(this.fullscreen.bind(this));
  },
  fullscreen: function (){
    var height = watcher.height();
    var width = watcher.width();

    this.menu.setHeight(40);
    this.mainPanel.onResize(height - 40, width);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the 'not scaling back when I went back to portrait' problem.

I got it working with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.6, user-scalable=no" />
```

for basic scaling back and forth, on 3G with iOS 4, as I change orientation.

I originally used "minimum-scale=1.0", got it to work when I replaced it with "initial-scale=1.0", after I saw the suggestions here.

Answer (score 1):

try this
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024" />`

Answer (score 1):

Just set the viewport directive to...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes|no" />
```

...no need to use JavaScript and you can still allow the user to scale the page should they wish.

Answer (score 1):

We faced the same issue in JQuery Mobile 1.3.0 also, we used the below and it worked

**in css**

```
body { /* IOS page orientation change resize issue*/  
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none ; 
}
```

and if still the header/footer does not resizes correctly (optional)

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
   $("div[data-role=header]").width($(window).width());
   $("div[data-role=footer]").width($(window).width());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using XHTML rather than HTML?

Try this, ensuring you close your first `meta` tag correctly.

```
<meta name="viewport" content ="user-scalable=no, width=device-width"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Safari on iOS 5 and lower (A.K.A. Safari Viewport Scaling Bug).

Try to avoid fix with meta viewport tags that disables the zoom gesture; instead, use this JavaScript fix:
https://gist.github.com/901295

More info about this bug: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/iphone-safari-viewport-scaling-bug

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my iPhone 5.  The answer was incredibly simple.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

This properly displays the page in either view, all the time, and offers scalability.

Comment: This causes inconsistencies in iOS and Android. Android sizes the landscape view properly. iOS does not.